# Visual Studio 2013 running unit test

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, test-explorer

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and I have a legacy solution that I need to modify, containing a a console application and a unit test project.

I want to run the console application project, and while it's running I also want to run one of my unit tests.

I run my console application, but when I go to the test explorer to run my unit test, the option is grayed out.

why is this, and how can I run my unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention *why* you want to do this, so I'll just answer blind.

If you run your console app without debugging, then you can run your unit tests at the same time.

To run without debugging, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (DEBUG -> Start Without Debugging).

Alternatively, open your console app's project folder, go to the bin\Debug folder and double-click on `<your_app>.exe`.

---

FWIW it doesn't sound like a very good idea to do this. Unit tests are meant to be runnable completely separately from your application.